# Append React Bootstrap Form to a div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am trying to append a Bootstrap form to a div. The function works perfect if I use regular `
  but not when trying to use the Bootstrap Form and elements. Im wondering if there is anyway at all to do this??? Or is this a limitation? And yes I did import react-bootstrap and currently have a similar form already on the page working fine. I just want to append another form...

````
{
  console.log("add new has been clicked")
  // get container of equipment
const eqContainer = document.getElementById("eqContainer");
const newForm =  `<Form.Group controlId="formeqid">
<Form.Control
  name="eqid"
  type="input"
  
/>
</Form.Group>`;
                 
eqContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',newForm)                

};```
````

Comment: Post your whole code. DOM manipulation is considered an anti-pattern in react. This is the probably not the way you would be doing this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just make an array and add to that array what i need on click and use .map to iterate over the array to create the forms needed. On click I just add a new object to the array and it appears as another form.